# ¿Cómo simulo el evento onFocus en react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Estoy migrando unas pruebas de EcmaScript a Typescript y tengo problemas en particular con esta línea:

```
wrapper.instance().focus();
```

que viene de este fragmento:

```
const suggestions: Array<React.ReactElement> = [React.createElement('p', null, 'afc163'), React.createElement('p', null, 'benjycui'), React.createElement('p', null, 'yiminghe'), React.createElement('p', null, 'RaoHai'), React.createElement('p', null, '中文'), React.createElement('p', null, 'にほんご')];
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Mention
        defaultValue={toContentState('@afc163')}
        onFocus={handleFocus}
        suggestions={suggestions}
      />,
    );
wrapper.instance().focus();
jest.runAllTimers();
expect(handleFocus).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
import * as React from 'react';
.
.
.
const focus = wrapper.find('Mention').prop('onFocus');
if (focus) {
  focus(new React.FocusEvent<HTMLElement>());
}
```

Pero obtengo el error

> Error:(29, 23) TS2339: Property 'FocusEvent' does not exist on type 'typeof React'.

Intenté además modificar el código a

```
wrapper.find('Mention').simulate('onFocus');
```

pero ahora me da el error

> Mention › should has focus function
>
> ```
> Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 2 found instead.
>
>   at ReactWrapper.single (node_modules/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js:1166:13)
>   at ReactWrapper.single [as simulate](node_modules/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js:665:17)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (components/mention/__tests__/index.test.js:26:1)
> ```

Comment: Has provado con refs?

Comment: @Andres9619 no, no sé ni que es un ref

Answer (score 0):

Los refs proporcionan una forma de acceder a los nodos del DOM o a elementos React creados en el método de renderizado.
Con jsx podrias hacer algo asi:

```
class App extends React.Component{
      nameInput = null;
      componentDidMount(){
        this.nameInput && this.nameInput.focus();
      }
      render() {
        return(
          <div>
            <input 
              ref={(input) => { this.nameInput = input; }} 
              defaultValue="will focus"
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```